# Primefaces 3.0 DataTable inCell editing , RowEditEvent doesn't retrieve updated field

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on a sample app with primefaces 3 , using datatables incell editing mode. Although when i edit , i see the event.getObjects gives me the object which is not modified.

Changed the property of the object on debug mode, it does update.

So i couldn't figure out why i cant get the edited property.

Below are my eventlistener method and the xhtml;

Any pointers are welcomed

Thanks in advance

**EventListener**

```
public void editListener(RowEditEvent event){
    System.out.println("EDIT LISTENER");
    update((Employer)event.getObject());

}
```

**JSF :**

```
   <h:form id="form">
                <h1><h:outputText value="List"/></h1>
                <p:dataTable value="#{employer.employers}" var="item" paginator="true" rows="10" style="width:300px">
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Id"/>
                        </f:facet>

                        <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Name">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText value="#{item.name}"></p:inputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Surname"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.surname}"/>

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Phone"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.phone}"/>

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.email}"/>

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">
                        <p:rowEditor />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{employer.editListener}"></p:ajax>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

Comment: Verify that there is not a validation error on some other input component on the form that would prevent the edit from being successful.  Also I believe in Primefaces 3 you should have a `rowKey` attribute for the dataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this...

```
<p:dataTable value="#{employer.employers}" var="item" paginator="true" 
    rows="10" style="width:300px">
```

...put the following:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{HandlerClassName.rowEditListener}" />
```