# Primefaces row edit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am searching this forum for primefaces rowedit. I am using primeface 3.5. I tried this link

[Primefaces 3.0 DataTable inCell editing , RowEditEvent doesn't retrieve updated field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054792/primefaces-3-0-datatable-incell-editing-roweditevent-doesnt-retrieve-updated)

[primefaces rowediting datatable ejb update returns old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874834/primefaces-rowediting-datatable-ejb-update-returns-old-data)

but i still have problems. For me its just displaying the old values and not the new one which i changed.

Here is my code:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{sIRRatesMB.onEditMaterialRate}"  /> 

<p:column headerText="Category Description" style="width:30%"> 
    <p:cellEditor>  
        <f:facet name="output">  
            <h:outputText value="#{Material.categoryDescription}" />  
        </f:facet>  

        <f:facet name="input">  
            <p:inputText value="#{Material.categoryDescription}" style="width:100%"/>  
        </f:facet>   
    </p:cellEditor>  
</p:column>
```

and

```
public void onEditMaterialRate(RowEditEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Material on edit get desc" + ((MaterialRates) event.getObject()).getCategoryDescription());
    sIRRatesSB.updateMaterialRates((MaterialRates) event.getObject());
}
```

What I have done is exactly as given in one of the above links.

It not even getting the object and printing it. Thanx in advance.

Comment: You should add the `<p:dataTable />` start line at least, also bean getter/setter related with your table data.

Comment: that and all is done. I just showed the code which suit the question. the program is working and getting output. But instead of getting the new values I am getting old values, thats all

Comment: In onEditMaterialRate method update the list for your datatable.

Comment: @RaghavendaBhat I mean in the question, without that it is hard to help you.

Comment: @Alexandre Lavoie... :) it works. I added getter/setter as u said .Thnx. Actually it was not there in my Managed Bean.